# MongoDB (with C# driver), is there any log?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'd like to know if there're any log when you try for example to insert something into field **Name** of document Customer. But the field Name has been renamed in the mongodb for **FirstName** ?

Because I just tried something like that, I renamed every field's name called **Name** into **FirstName** of my collection of Customer document. And in my C# code, I have a query which used to work, it removes a customer with Name "John". I execute it, the query runs without errors but nothing happens in the database. It should tell me that field **Name** doesn't exist anymore. How do you detect that ?

Thanks.
John

[EDIT]
my C# code:

```
public void DeleteOverride(Guid applicationId, string settingKey, string name)
{
   var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", applicationId), Query.EQ("Settings.Key", settingKey));
   var update = Update.Pull("Settings.$.Overrides", new BsonDocument {{"Name", name}});
   Run(database => database.GetCollection<ApplicationViewModel>("Applications").Update(query, update));
 }
```

Here's in my example: the field **Name** has been renamed for **DefinedFor** in the dababase for every documents of my collection Application, I run it, and no exceptions has been thrown. My visual studio has CLR exceptions enabled.

Comment: This is strange, and you should not need Mongo's log for this. C# should give you an error. I am not a c# guy, but this kind of stuff usually happens when you suppress exceptions. Or for some reason IDE is not showing up errors may be.

Comment: yes that's weird. Through, I did was in debug mode with visual studio. But you're right, it's C# code which should throw an exception. I'm gonna edit my first post my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such log. You should care about fields renaming yourself.

You can write unit test for each update to make sure that updates work correctly and detect problems with renames.

I guess string names in queries/updates is the weakest side of the official driver.

Comment: yeah excellent solution. I will do unit test for each tests. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is a schema free database so there is no such thing as a "field no longer exists" error. Any field may or may not exist, so its absence is not an error.

A future version of the C# driver will support LINQ, which will catch some errors at compile time, and will also handle the mapping from the C# property name to the BSON element name, which should help avoid most mismatches.

Comment: Omg, cool. I'm looking forward to use Linq with MongoDB. A dream comes true!